# OpenPGPJS: Error decrypting message: No symmetrically encrypted session key packet found

Tags: encryption, openpgp.js

Below is my simple code (trying to learn how PGP works):

```
requirejs(['./openpgp'], function(openpgp) {

    openpgp.initWorker({
        path: './openpgp.worker.js'
    });

    openpgp.config.aead_protect = true;


    var fileContents = "Hello world!!";

    var encryptionCode = function(e) {
        var options;
        var encrypted;
        var myKey = {};

        myKey.pubkey = 
`-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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==
=Xm9f
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
`;

        myKey.privkey = 
`-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

lQOsBFjMFRwBCACtu5EG8GusNpr5O4wrb3fykjPegUh9KD/ErWrplmXcbtp6T/XH
FPkc5cyMme7PxxlcFy3fshMDPg0adTGi8/TPygmO9THtjHYqynge0hxDyafP39xE
2DKkyuLyV3KxNiUfr+NUB3MQHktqiS/pPK1MJUQdHjYPHax5QT1bMgffx36tM5vo
d3rdu4AMmLgnSlakmWus/hHMFUgXdp4Q0LWf7uVTXTwbnTkfLQOumj+1SiYV40BL
rxgiyW172uqy6/hqK9JgOvAUjWZiO9aNyexENzA8Y+Oyy3OWX91CKTYiE2eQKhFK
YlTf/AFgrnFd0wgAFkZ0dWj51x7kH1a1Ks8/ABEBAAH/AwMCAqaV72qGxntgHjJJ
u1IAcTFlGt4e5nXAWGz9nMhQ84p4gHPT3wecMFul9Y8f3Xe8E6+bfaqESrtAaw28
UeRK3HpkYOYgcamC/iIMyZ8/GyqI/VrWpu+ola0WnLQUu58HogpHuk8ezb9Lfypq
qQVp3rTd58sT/RG/25cwSl5QDWZcE2CWTFc9SuwjtRlTj++Hw1ckqGQsGpVoGA3G
Gk5lfK06a3GqDzCaoNG5NUUjKEFhxUfOUCOfV2pyUT+9SBc+HoUptJ/csA/kPCB6
8xW3ycAQFLpYIqLcOJ9H3EMb8FIat2fPyaaocs+yIcYI0VLqS46Rhkj4apBQ8X5d
n3xlL32X/0CA5QKt6ybfXI6uHWvjbyyFl6bw8f8V23fyAXBiqLvz1stGtHTt/IWS
4j2MtOVxOumFY+dG2IHfyWfvh561drasQovtwh9diB4k96dnPYFwlG/8WRkhNF3R
Gkjwy0KOkr/LuvY7H9gFhyYDrXmXrcF3lUYxbQqou4V7nYOKynCGs8phWIezFVbN
4W0ew0rU4MqyAMdZ2YGM/hILSc2/RtufNR/nlPTe7mMGto8TjeVE0LTWcVs+I+A9
Iep0zwJLhdDGH5i0TcHPgxO+mzfcU2V5TrzLMuAlz9xZz3PKHlPMd5GV6THAMHM5
ZJB7P7skxC1zHdL0C00BFxG3QpDMKlFqozE2al7rizU0TtpGPWeOFRjThLuG+4wE
k+zj0EYSxsye7JRkpktMaX0DKk5dtSJn8lcFPR425E+clCwAWyd6Nhf0xEGWbRtL
D2OUWU//FQpDNS74+1EWWiEvfkuz9hZDk19KmpB6amiu4nuyzQJvWB8+gNiSNPZs
af95YSRueaPUYwMFTEhXVZGj1ZX0fM6dfxi4BE/JM7QNcmF2aUB0ZXN0LmNvbYkB
HAQQAQIABgUCWMwVHAAKCRBzTNXW57NhVI3xB/41jJW8orYdsX5CfuP4R3R6wrY5
LrFWp2UV9RIBSrURHXd99zgNquP1nYsm469DgzXUhiWitcZ22JrLnmhP/GiWMOsc
chjOVDiHo7M4k/ohTEhLSeq0pkIuG+8Rgv+85v8B44xKj9lYcPVGMKem/S9VeSLh
T6QAjz6F8j9BCtVyjzfFaEfTKI78cfR4dUuQCICtqq/TNNJfq22mdgPIr6bAse1u
BbPONSLUpms21HYItTycJSPIctq7VuRmfKyruYACfr1URUBDzfdacrAEbu4izKaV
xmIK060irjSQ/XDKw5uSB8uQPfstbdWnNjaLj7CJZruLy0Fgy+bnwFhMIuC4
=Qx/K
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`;

        options = {
            data: fileContents,
            publicKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(myKey.pubkey).keys
        };

        openpgp.encrypt(options).then(function(ciphertext) {
            myKey.encrypted = ciphertext.data;
            console.log("Encrypted: ", myKey.encrypted);

            options = {
                message: openpgp.message.readArmored(myKey.encrypted),     // parse armored message
                privateKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(myKey.privkey).keys[0],
                "password": "abcd@1234"
            };

            openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {
                console.log("plaintext", plaintext);
                return plaintext.data;
            });

        });

    }(this);

});
```

I have generated public and private keys from online site. Its just for testing purpose.

I can see that the string has been encoded properly (console.log). But at the time of decryption, it throws exception Error decrypting message: No symmetrically encrypted session key packet found

What I am doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I figured out that, I had to decrypt my private key in order to decrypt the message.

The following code helped me to complete the encrypt/decrypt demo:

```
options = {
    message: openpgp.message.readArmored(myKey.encrypted),
    privateKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(myKey.privkey).keys[0].decrypt('abcd@1234'),
    "password": "abcd@1234"
};

openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {
    console.log("Encrypted message got decrypted: ", plaintext.data);
    return plaintext.data;
});
```

Thanks.